# Placing a PIC image in an arbitrary position of the page using ms macros

Tags: linux, unix, groff, troff

I have an image defined using PIC and incorporated to a groff ms document.

I notice that I need to encapsulate the image inside a `.DS L - .DE` block to have it aligned to left. Otherwise is centered.

What shall be done to have the image in a file and be able to position the image anywhere in the page? (specifying coordinates).

This is what I have tried:

```
\h'2in'\v'4in'FOOTEXT\v'-4in'
```

But the problem is if you replace FOOTEXT with a `.PS .PE` image the image will be centered, and if you use `.DS L .DE` it does not work, the paragraph is displayed in its normal ms position.

While groff is not a mainstream tool anymore, I was wondering if someone using it could provide some help to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is one of the limitations of `pic`.  If you need to be more flexible, you can create an encapsulated postscript file of the PIC image:

```
pic blk.pic > blk.groff
groff blk.groff > blk.ps
eps2eps -B1  blk.ps blk.eps
```

and include that. This makes it even possible to use the PIC images in-line:

```
.P
An in-line picture is also possible, and it is not limited to
\v'0.12v'
.dospark block/blk.eps 21.4 12
\v'-0.12v'
pic images.
.P
```

Note: `dospark` is a macro by Ted Harding.